# Problems with Visibility Binding in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I don't know why but my Visibility Binding isn't working ONLY in the DataTemplate. Did I forget something?
Edit: All Bindings (except for this one work perfectly)
Thats the structure.

```
<Window>
<Grid>
<Grid>
<Grid Grid.Row="5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>                
                  <ItemsControl x:Name="Targets" Margin="0,4,0,4">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Tag="{Binding}" PreviewKeyDown="ChangeLocationAddress" PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="TxtGotKeyboardFocusHandler" LostKeyboardFocus="ChangeLocationAddress" />
                                <Button Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Content=" ↑ " Click="MoveLocationUp" Visibility="Visible" /> 
                                <Button Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Content=" ↓ "  Click="MoveLocationDown" Visibility="{Binding Path = UpDownButtonVisibility, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
           <Button x:Name="btnNewAddress" Grid.Row="1" Content="Neues Ziel hinzufügen" Margin="0,4,0,4" Visibility="{Binding Path=TargetButtonVisibility}"/>
        </Grid>
</Grid></Grid></Grid></Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public MapView(){
 this.DataContext = this.ViewModel = new MapVM();
 this.InitializeComponent();
 this.Targest.Itemssource = this.ViewModel.ToLocations;
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public MapVM()
        {   this.UpDownButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            this.TargetButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
 private Visibility _UpDownButtonVisibility;
    /// <summary>
    /// Property Visibility für "↓" und "↑"
    /// </summary>
    public Visibility UpDownButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return _UpDownButtonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            this._UpDownButtonVisibility = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UpDownButtonVisibility");
        }
    }
public Visibility TargetButtonVisibility { get; set; }
```

EDIT:
Program Output:
    BindingExpression path error: 'UpDownButtonVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''Location' (HashCode=-794088449)'. BindingExpression:Path=UpDownButtonVisibility; DataItem='Location' (HashCode=-794088449); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')   1.10s

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is TargetButtonVisibility declared?  Check into that for why the other isn't working.  My first guess is an issue with you not notifying the UI of changes for UpDownButtonVisibility, but without seeing the other one, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of your `TargetButtonVisibility` binding is your main `MapVM`. This works ok.

The `DataContext` within your `DataTemplate` is **not** MapVM, is it the **item being displayed** by the template.

Since you have not supplied any `ItemsSource` binding on your `ItemsControl` we have no way of knowing what this actually is.

Also, as unkreativ points out, do not use Visibility in your VM, since this is a view related type. Use bool instead and call the property IsUpDownButtonVisible or similar.

**EDIT:** Assuming you do actually **want** to bind to your single `MapVM`, you could use a `RelativeSource` to find the parent `ItemsControl`:

```
<Button Margin="2,0,0,0" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Content=" ↓ "  
        Click="MoveLocationDown" 
        Visibility="{Binding DataContext.UpDownButtonVisibility,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>
```

However, since you've already named your `ItemsControl` (`Targets`), you can simply refer to it by name:

```
<Button Margin="2,0,0,0" 
        Grid.Column="2" 
        Content=" ↓ "  
        Click="MoveLocationDown" 
        Visibility="{Binding DataContext.UpDownButtonVisibility,
                             ElementName=Targets}"/>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the problem,
I hope I added enough information.

Now, how can I bind correctly?

Comment: Thank you!
Now I understand WHY I didn't work and now it does.

Answer (score 1):

Change string to Visibility

```
public Visibility UpDownButtonVisibility { get; set; }
this.UpDownButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Add INPC and binding to a View model.

Here is working sample:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="ItemsControlDataTemplate.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControlDataTemplate"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="Targets" Margin="0,4,0,4" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Text="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Tag="{Binding}" />
                        <Button Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Content=" ↑ " Visibility="Visible" />
                        <Button Margin="2,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2" Content=" ↓ "   Visibility="{Binding Path=UpDownButtonVisibility}"/>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<MapVM> _items = new ObservableCollection<MapVM>();

    public ObservableCollection<MapVM> Items { get { return _items; } }


    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new MapVM() { UpDownButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible, Address = "1111111" });
        Items.Add(new MapVM() { UpDownButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed, Address = "222222" });
        Items.Add(new MapVM() { UpDownButtonVisibility = Visibility.Visible, Address = "33333333" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}




class MapVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MapVM()
    {
        this.UpDownButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.TargetButtonVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private Visibility _upDownButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility UpDownButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return _upDownButtonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _upDownButtonVisibility = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(UpDownButtonVisibility)));
        }
    }


    private Visibility _targetButtonVisibility;
    public Visibility TargetButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return _targetButtonVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _targetButtonVisibility = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TargetButtonVisibility)));
        }
    }

    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
        set
        {
            _address = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Address)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that quick answer.. but:
that didn't help. :(

though this.TargetButtonVisibility = "Collapsed" is working

Comment: Could yuo please update your post with more XAML and ViewModel, you are binding to.

Comment: Try to trigger property changed event when UpDownButtonVisibility property is changed.

Comment: Seems that you bind your MapVM to DataContext of the window, that is why binding to TargetButtonVisibility property works. While each of items in ItemControl try to bind to UpDownButtonVisibility of it's own DataContext, and can't find it. Have a look to Output window in your Visual Studio, it should show binding errors.

Comment: That could be the problem!

Activated Event Time Duration Thread
 BindingExpression path error: 'UpDownButtonVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''Location' (HashCode=-794088449)'. BindingExpression:Path=UpDownButtonVisibility; DataItem='Location' (HashCode=-794088449); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility') 1.10s  

It should be MapVM, shouldn't it?

Comment: I suppose that your Location class should contain UpDownButtonVisibility property. Please see sample code that I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a PropertyChanged event handler and a call to it in your code. Add the INotifyPropertyChanged to your DataContext object and it should work

Personally I would model the visibility as a bool and use the BooleasnToVisibility Converter that comes with WPF.